# Serialized string or plain PHP, which is faster to parse?

Tags: php, performance, serialization

I'm going to have a file with about 5 MB size and I have 2 options:

1. Read a **plain PHP array** from a file using **include** function.
2. Read a **serialize/json converted array** from a file using **file_get_contents** function then decode it.

Which one will be faster? I'm going to use it as cache.

Comment: I think the former option is faster. But you won’t know until you test and profile both variants.

Comment: if array is flat, consider also parse_ini_file

Comment: Are you sure you're not pre-optimizing here? I don't think either method should be a performance bottleneck. I'd just go with whichever method you are more comfortable with, or otherwise fits with the project the most. Optimization does not sound important here.

Comment: Why don't you test both variants and then post results here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a serialized array is much faster, even if you use a bytecode cache.

Comment: What do you base that statement on?

Comment: @troelskn, both methods involve loading a file into memory, but option 1 involves a full php interpreter, while option 2 just involves a json parser. The php interpreter is a much more complicated machine than a json parser, so I would suspect that AndreKR is correct.

Comment: @troelskn In our company we came across this question many times and checked in a lot of different environments and it turned out that the unserialize method was always faster by several times.

Comment: @ben_lee Maybe. I was interested in knowing if it was a guess or based in facts.

Answer (score 4):

Initially when I looked at the question I guessed that PHP+opcode caching would be faster than serialized php, but after a few benchmark I found out I was wrong. `unserialize` performed about 4x better than `require`. Though writing PHP via `var_export` seems to be faster than `serialize`. PHP format also has the advantage of being human readable.

[image]

Note: I ran the tests with PHP 5.3.3 and used a ram disk as my temp folder.

If you have memory to spare (and APC installed), I would suggest using `apc_store`. I didn't benchmark it, but I'd expect it to be much faster than file based caching.

```
<?

function writestuff( $folder, $data ) {
    $start = microtime( TRUE );
    file_put_contents( "$folder/array.data", serialize( $data ) );
    print ( microtime( TRUE ) - $start ).",";


    $start = microtime( TRUE );
    file_put_contents( "$folder/array.php", "<? return ".var_export( $data, TRUE ).";" );
    print ( microtime( TRUE ) - $start ).",";
}

function readstuff( $folder ) {
    $start = microtime( TRUE );
    $data = unserialize( file_get_contents( "$folder/array.data" ) );
    print ( microtime( TRUE ) - $start ).",";
    unset( $data );

    apc_clear_cache();
    if( ! apc_compile_file( "$folder/array.php" ) )
        throw new Exception( "didn't cache" );

    $start = microtime( TRUE );
    $data = require( "$folder/array.php" );
    print ( microtime( TRUE ) - $start )."\n";
    unset( $data );
}

$folder = $_GET["folder"];

for( $i = 1; $i < 10000; $i += 10 ) {
    $data = range( 0, $i );
    print $i.",";
    writestuff( $folder, $data );
    readstuff( $folder );

}

?>
```

Comment: how have you generated the graph? :o

Comment: Excel 2011 Mac, scatter graph.